# Why do we need a push notification provider with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, backend

I am completely new to the whole concept of push notifications. I have written a back-end server and I will send push notifications from it to the Android app, which is also written by me. But my question is:

**Do I really need, or why would I need a Push notification service?**

Thanks!

Comment: What's the nature of the app you're working on?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use FCM to send push notifications, at some point in time, someone has to make a request to Google's FCM service, because Google is the only one, who can send a message to a device via FCM. Same applies for APNS, at some point in time, someone has to make a request to Apple's APNS service

Depending on your requirements, you can do this yourself in your own code or you can use some 3rd party provider. Using a 3rd party provider MAY have benefits. For instance they may take care of token management, or provide a single request for sending to Android and iOS devices, and so on and so forth. But in the end of the day, also a 3rd party provider sends out requests to Google or Apple in your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase cloud messaging service or using socket programming for this .